# Want home page to click through to two different page types

Tags: customization, pages, homepage

Looking for correct vocabulary to accomplish the following:

Home page to show small images for following pages.  On click through, (editor chooses) to display distinct page type:
EITHER 1: Page that displays in sequence: long text description, multiple images.
OR 2. Page that displays image-only gallery with simple  right-left arrow navigation to short series of images.  Both types of pages will exist on the site. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For that you can create two templates and assign both templates to both pages.

Add those pages to menu and give them both the label `Home`.

Now its working like your site has a two home pages.